# How to send props to component by using useNavigate in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to directly send props to a component. Is there a way to do this?

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(()=>{

                .....
        
     
                    navigate ("/projectpage"); //send props here
           
    },[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of tackling this need is to pass the data as params to your navigation that you can access with the useParams hook.

[Here's the docs from React Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

[Here's a good guide on how to use it in practice](https://ui.dev/react-router-url-parameters)